# Using Tesseract 4 in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tesseract

I am struggle to use tesseract ocr in windows. Here is what I have installed:
tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v4.0.0-rc1.20181002.exe from here:

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

[image]

and I have installed on my machine. After that, I have setup the environment variable

[image]

but when I am trying to get text from image, with this command:

```
C:\Users\flaviu.marc>tesseract c:\Flaviu\imagine.png C:\Flaviu\output.txt
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error opening data file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

Can you help me to solve my problem ? I am trying to use tesseract into VC++ app, but I get exactly the same errors just like I use tesseract from command line.

After I updated the environment variable:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\flaviu.marc>tesseract c:\Flaviu\imagine.png C:\Flaviu\output.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine vv4.0.0-rc1.20181002 with Leptonica
Error in pixReadStreamPng: spp == 1, cmap, trans array, invalid depth: 4
```

Later edit: if I have tried another image, the initialization is working now, but I still have some error messages:

```
Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
```

Why I encounter these errors ? Because when I try to run the classic code (pImage is NULL)

```
Pix* pImage = pixRead(sFileName);
if(NULL == pImage)
{
    m_sError.Format(_T("Could not read image with leptonica."));
    return sRet;
}
```

Code is taken from here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample

Here is how I compiled leptonica:
[image]

how can compile libtiff ? I have no option for that ...

Comment: Check out this short but working tutorial on tesseract : https://youtu.be/2fmzooBKp8A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TESSDATA_PREFIX` should be pointing to the directory with traineddata files for example:

[tessdata default](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)

[tessdata good quality but slow](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best)

[tessdata fast but lower quality](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast)

Comment: I updated the answer. I pass by from initial error though.

Comment: That error means that something is wrong with your image. Try to run tesseract on another image.

Comment: I would suggest you to make another question regarding your last errors. In that case leptonica experts would more likely see the questions and would be able to help. Also it would help other users with similar problem, because question name would better describe the issue you have.

Comment: But at first glance it looks like leptonica was built without libtiff

Comment: I don't think I had this option (to compile or not libtiff), nor in leptonica nor in tesseract ...

Comment: And how to get this libtiff ? Because I don't have any option of this kind when I compiled leptonica ...